# Preg match that allows double quotation marks

Tags: php, regex

Working on returning results from an API.

Currently having 2 issues using the right preg_match expression

the first is for a keyword search. I need to allow a-zA-Z and double quotation marks as it allows an exact phrase search ie) "Sales Manager"

here is what I have now, Will this work? I believe if a special character is within a class[] then I dont need to escape it? In sublime 2 it looks like im wrong by the colored text.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z "]*S/", $query)) {
            //do this
        }
```

The second is a search by location where I need to allow a-zA-Z0-9 and a comma. ie) Syracuse, NY or a zip code.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9,\,]*S/", $location){
            //do this
        }
```

Comment: When your PHP string uses `"` double quotes around, then you need to escape it within.

Comment: "Will this work?" Did you... try it?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a nice regex testing tool than can definitely assist beginners like myself.

http://www.phpliveregex.com

Mario was correct that it did in fact need to be escaped.

Here's what worked for me:

Search

```
if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z \"]*\S[a-zA-Z \"]/", $query)) {
        //do this
    }
```

Location

```
if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.]*\S[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.]*\S[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.]/", $location){
        //do this
    }
```

I added a period as another character to allow in case there was a city starting with St.

Thanks @Mario for the explanation.